# Mongo query how to retrieve the latest inserted array value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection which contains some array values such as ActivityType, Note and ActivityDate. The array name is called activities. I need to rename some fields so I used aggregate and $project to rename some columns for the output. But I only need to return the latest inserted ActivityDate for the array value.

My current query returns all the array value in the Activity array:

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {$match: {}
},   {$unwind: "$activities"},
        {$match: {}},



{ "$project": {
         "_id" : 0,
      "Project Number": "$ProjectNumber" ,
      "Activity Type": "$activities.activityTypeDesc" ,
      "Date of Activity": { 
                "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$activities.dateOfActivity" } 
            }
    }}
   ])
```

It is sort of like getting the top 1 order by  in sql server. How do I do that in Mongodb? After some reading seems like I need to use $sort and $group, but I don't know how to fit in here.

I have some sample data below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd289a93f7cf02c36837ca7"),
    "ProjectNumber" : "ABC1234567",
    "activities" : [ 
        {
            "activityTypeDesc" : "Type1",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-02-20T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "activityNote" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "activityTypeDesc" : "Type2",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-03-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "activityNote" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "activityTypeDesc" : "Type3",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-01-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "activityNote" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "activityTypeDesc" : "Type4",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-04-15T05:00:00.000Z"),
            "activityNote" : ""
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd2ca65d1a01d157c0179be"),
    "ProjectNumber" : "12345",
    "activities" : []
}
```

The result of the query should return two rows, one with the lastest activitydate , one with no activitydate (as no array value)
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what is your exact requirement, you want to get latest element from array or just need to rename the field name?

Comment: I need both. I need to get all the array elements that has the latest activitydate on it, but I also need to rename the columns to something else.

Comment: ok, how will you decide which element has latest activity date?

Comment: I have an array in the document, like following: 
 "activities" : [ 
        {
            "activityTypeDesc" : "Type1",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-02-20T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "activityNote" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "activityTypeDesc" : "Type2",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-03-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "activityNote" : ""
        }
    ]. So I only need to get the latest set of array values order by dateOfActivity. But outside the array I have other fields that I need to rename them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `activities` array
- `$sort` by `dateOfActivity` in descending order
- `$group` by `_id` and get first activity required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$activities",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "activities.dateOfActivity": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "Project Number": { $first: "$ProjectNumber" },
      "Activity Type": { $first: "$activities.activityTypeDesc" },
      "Date Of Activity": {
        $first: {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
            "date": "$activities.dateOfActivity"
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0N9ZO5icnix)

Comment: Thanks. The above query only returns the array on the desending order of DateOfActivity. But I only need to get the latest. Meaning top 1. So the current query returns the array below:

 "activities" : [ 
        {
            "Activity Type" : "Type1",
            "Date Of Activity" : "3921-02-09"
        }, 
        {
            "Activity Type" : "Type2",
            "Date Of Activity" : "2021-02-07"
        }
    ],

Comment: while what I need is only returning : 

"activities" : [ 
        {
            "Activity Type" : "Type1",
            "Date Of Activity" : "3921-02-09"
        }
    ], 

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: can you confirm this https://mongoplayground.net/p/tCRKjly1AzE

Comment: Nevermind. I am able to return only the first record by adding $first, 

 $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "Project Name": { $first: "$ProjectName" },
      "Activity Type" : {$first: "$activities.activityTypeDesc"},
      "Date Of Activity": { $first: {"$dateToString" : { "format": "%Y-%m-%d","date": "$activities.dateOfActivity"}}}
   , but I notice that there are some data are missing, those are the data have no the array value , meaning Date of Activity are null. Those should be return as well. How can I add them back?

Comment: which activity are null i am not getting you just look at this working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CvWufpEd4f4), if you are still getting null then add sample data in this playground and share

Comment: I don't know whether I am doing it right, it threw me error on configuration. Check this link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uHrv8TaHXX_

Comment: So the left side is the collection. It has two documents. One has 4 array value, one has no array value. The query on the right is the query that I am using, it should return 2 rows, one with the latest activityDate, one with no data on the activityDate (meaning null). Right now, the query only returns one row with the data who has the activityDate.

Comment: look at this https://mongoplayground.net/p/ceaBz20P68f

Comment: I see. Great, you are adding preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true. That works. Another question, how can I not display _id? From $Project, I can use -1, but on $group, looks like it is needed.

Comment: you can't in group, you have to add new stage after group, `{ $project: { _id: 0 } }`

Comment: so if I have 10 fields, I need to add them all on $group and $project?

Comment: yes for [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and as per requirements in [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), i can't explain it here you have to look the particular link and learn. if you have any question please post new question.